# If $f(z)=\sum c_nz^n$ is an entire function of finite genus $\mu$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n(n!)^{1/(\mu+1)}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, entire-functions

If $f(z)=\sum c_nz^n$ is an entire function of finite genus $\mu$ then prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n(n!)^{1/(\mu+1)}=0.$$

I know that if $f$ is an entire function of finite genus $\mu$, then $f$ is of finite order $\lambda\leq\mu+1$. In particular, I have $|f(z)|\lt \exp(|z|^{\beta})$ holds for all large enough $|z|$, where $\beta=\mu+1$. Now, using a previous [estimate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3656897/if-fz-sum-a-nzn-is-an-entire-function-of-finite-order-then-a-n-leq-f), I get $$|c_n|\leq \Bigl(\frac{e\beta}{n}\Bigl)^{n/\beta}$$ for all large enough $n$. Thus, 
$$\begin{align*}
|c_n|(n!)^{1/\beta}
&\leq \Bigl(\frac{e\beta}{n}\Bigl)^{n/\beta}(n!)^{1/\beta}\\
&\sim \Bigl(\frac{e\beta}{n}\Bigl)^{n/\beta}\Bigl(\sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\Bigl)^{1/\beta}\\
&=\beta^{n/\beta}(2 \pi n)^{1/2\beta}.
\end{align*}$$
However, this doesn't help much. I don't think $\beta^{n/\beta}(2 \pi n)^{1/2\beta}$ converges to $0$.

Now, if I just use the Cauchy's estimate, I have 
\begin{align*}
|c_n|(n!)^{1/\beta}&\leq \frac{\exp(n^{\beta})}{n^n} (n!)^{1/\beta}\\
&\sim \frac{\exp(n^{\beta})}{n^n}\Bigl(\sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\Bigl)^{1/\beta}\\
&=(2 \pi)^{1/2\beta}\exp(n^{\beta}-n/\beta)n^{n/\beta+1/2\beta-n}.
\end{align*}
I don't have much experience in computing estimates. Can someone help me out to complete any of the arguments?

---

This is Exercise $2.1$ from Chapter ${\rm XI}$ of Conway's *functions of one complex variable*. The **hint** given is to use the *Cauchy's estimates*. I found [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h34652p215066) AoPS post using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/), however, they mistook the genus for the order. Also, the definition of the "genus"(order) mentioned in the above post comes only after this exercise in Conway(Exercise $2.5$).

Here's the definition of the order Conway uses:

**Definition.** An entire function $f$ is of *finite order* if there is a positive constant $a$ and an $r_0\gt0$ such that $|f(z)|\lt \exp(|z|^a)$ for $|z|\gt r_0$. If $f$ is of finite order, then $$\lambda=\inf\{a\mid |f(z)|\lt \exp(|z|^a)\,\text{for $|z|$ sufficiently large}\}$$ is called the *order* of $f$. Equivalently, $$\lambda=\limsup_{r\to\infty}\frac{\log\log M(r)}{\log r},$$ where $M(r)=\max\{|f(z)|\mid|z|=r\}$.

Of course, all three are equivalent, but I would like to see a proof using the hint and the above two definitions.

Comment: I cannot see any flaws in your argument. Is the statement correct?

Comment: This is Exercise $2.1$ from Chapter ${\rm XI}$ of Conway's *functions of one complex variable*.

Comment: Yes, it seems that the statement is true when the order equals to the genus, since $$
\mathop {\lim \inf }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{\log (1/\left| {c_n } \right|)}}{{n\log n}} = \frac{1}{\mu } > \frac{1}{{\mu  + 1}}.
$$
I cannot see how does it follow when the order is $\mu+1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Partial answer.** Suppose that the order of $f(z)$ is $\lambda$. As you already noted, $\lambda  \le \mu  + 1$. Let us consider the case that $\lambda <\mu+1$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda } - \frac{1}{{\mu  + 1}} = \varepsilon,
$$
with a suitable positive $\varepsilon$. Since
$$
\mathop {\lim \inf }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{{ - \log \left| {c_n } \right|}}{{n\log n}} = \frac{1}{\lambda },
$$
it holds that
$$
\frac{{ - \log \left| {c_n } \right|}}{{n\log n}} \geq \frac{1}{\lambda } -\frac{\varepsilon }{2},
$$
for all $n\geq n_0$ with a suiable $n_0\geq 0$ that depends on $\varepsilon$. Hence, for all $n\geq n_0\geq 0$,
\begin{align*}
c_n (n!)^{1/(\mu  + 1)} & = \exp \left( { - \left[ {\frac{{ - \log \left| {c_n } \right|}}{{n\log n}} - \frac{1}{{\mu  + 1}}\frac{{\log n!}}{{n\log n}}} \right]n\log n} \right)
\\ &
 \le \exp \left( { - \left[ {\frac{1}{\lambda } - \frac{\varepsilon }{2} - \frac{1}{{\mu  + 1}}\frac{{\log n!}}{{n\log n}}} \right]n\log n} \right) \\ & = \exp \left( { - \left[ {\frac{\varepsilon }{2} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\log n}}} \right)} \right]n\log n} \right) .
\end{align*}
Taking the limit of both sides, yields the claim.

Comment: By Stirling's formula, $\log n! = n\log n-n+\mathcal{O}(\log n)$.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. If it was $\mathcal{O}(1)$, we could not guarantee that $\varepsilon/2+\mathcal{O}(1)$ is positive for sufficiently large values of $n$. The way I did it, $\varepsilon /2+\mathcal{O}(1/\log n)$ will eventually become at least $\varepsilon /4$, say. So the exponent is always negative for large $n$ and it tends to infinity in magnitude.

Comment: Sorry, yes. You missed the $1$ initially. Your last comment is correct. In my calculation the $1$ multiplying $-1/(\mu+1)$ yields with $1/\lambda$ an $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Hi again. I have started a bounty. Do you have any insights on the $\lambda=\mu+1$ case?

Comment: I took a look at Conway's book. He suggests the use of a Cauchy estimate. I did it for this special case of $\lambda=\mu+1$ and optimised with respect to the radius of the circle of integration. It did not give anything appropriate.